# Why doesn't the newly created thread obtain its tid through pthread_create() return argument but pthread_self()

Tags: linux, thread-safety, pthreads

This is the sample code for thread creation from “Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment”. As for thread creation, `err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, thr_fn, NULL);` can the newly created thread just use ntid to print its own threadID, rather than calling pthread_self()?

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t ntid;

void
printids(const char *s)
{
    pid_t       pid;
    pthread_t   tid;

    pid = getpid();
    tid = pthread_self();
    printf("%s pid %u tid %u (0x%x)\n", s, (unsigned int)pid,
      (unsigned int)tid, (unsigned int)tid);
}

void *
thr_fn(void *arg)
{
    printids("new thread: ");      /* for the newly created thread,can it
                                    * print its own threadID just using ntid, 
                                    * instead of calling pthread_self() 
                                    */
    return((void *)0);
}

int
main(void)
{
    int     err;

    err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, thr_fn, NULL);
    if (err != 0)
        err_quit("can't create thread: %s\n", strerror(err));
    printids("main thread:");
    sleep(1);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check spec:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html

```
pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
```

> Upon successful completion, pthread_create() shall store the ID of the created thread in the location referenced by thread.
>
> The calling thread can obtain the ID of the created thread through the return value of the pthread_create() function, and the newly created thread can obtain its ID by a call to pthread_self().

The problem is: `ntid` is variable of calling function;  even if it is global, the reading of this global variable from thread doesn't scale to two created threads or more.

Other problem is timing and order of execution. pthread_create writes thread id to `ntid` *after* new thread is created:

> Upon successful completion, pthread_create() shall store the ID of the created thread in the location referenced by thread.

So, it is unsafe to read `ntid` from created thread without synchronization, new thread may do read before actual value will be written to global.

So, you should use `pthread_self`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_self.html

> The pthread_self() function shall return the thread ID of the calling thread.
>
> The pthread_self() function provides a capability similar to the getpid() function for processes and the rationale is the same: *the creation call does not provide the thread ID to the created thread.*

Comment: Yeah, this spec is very clear. But on my ubuntu sytem man page, it just says:  > See pthread_self(3) for further information on the thread ID returned in *thread by pthread_create(). Unless real-time scheduling policies are being employed, after a call to pthread_create(), it is indeterminate which thread—the caller or the new thread—will next execute.      Sorry, I just try to make the format correctly

Comment: hel, your ubuntu man is not as good as Open Group SPEC. The linux man http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html says about pthread_self(3) only to set link to note in the pthread_self man page about format of thread_id returned: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html#NOTES "POSIX.1 allows an implementation wide freedom in choosing the type used to represent a thread ID; for example, representation using either an arithmetic type or a structure is permitted". It does not say "user should never use pthread_self; it is deprecated; got your id from create, yo!"

Comment: I see. About format in comment, ever time I try two spaces to make  Linebreaks, or `>` to make Simple blockquotes, I fail.

Comment: No line formatting in comments for anybody with less than 100 k reputation. And for no one with equal or more than 100k rep: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting -> Comment Formatting "Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available." & http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: interesting. Thanks